# Tensorflow: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input_image' with dtype float

Tags: python, tensorflow

I know this is a common error, but I'm failing to understand this issue. Here's my code:

```
def convert_image(url):

    checkpoint_file = './vgg_16.ckpt'

    input_tensor = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None,224,224,3), name='input_image')
    scaled_input_tensor = tf.scalar_mul((1.0/255), input_tensor)
    scaled_input_tensor = tf.subtract(scaled_input_tensor, 0.5)
    scaled_input_tensor = tf.multiply(scaled_input_tensor, 2.0)

    #Load the model
    sess = tf.Session()
    arg_scope = vgg_arg_scope()
    with slim.arg_scope(arg_scope):
        logits, end_points = vgg_16(scaled_input_tensor, is_training=False)
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    saver.restore(sess, checkpoint_file)

    response = requests.get(url)
    img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
    im = np.array(img, dtype='float32')
    im = im.reshape(-1,224,224,3)

    features = sess.run(end_points['vgg_16/fc7'], feed_dict={input_tensor: im})
    sess.close()
    return np.squeeze(features)
```

As you can see, I'm using the VGG_16 pretrained model to extract fc7 features. About 50% of the code simply gets the image from a URL and converts it to 224x224x3; the other 50% does the tensorflow work to actually get the feature representation.

The thing is, the first time I run this code it works fine. However, the second time, I get the above error. Of course, "im" is a float32, even when I'm getting this error. So I think the issue has to do with something messing up when I run this function for the 2nd time. If I had to guess, it has to do with the way "saver" is working, but I haven't been able to figure out exactly what.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is most probably due to your re-defining the input_tensor, instead of using the input placeholder within the VGG model. You can apply the transformations on the input image `im`, just before you feed it to the network.

Moreover, you load the model for each and every image.
Instead, load the model once, and then iterate over the list of images within a loop.
Something like this:

```
def convert_images(url_list):
   # Load the TF model
   #.....
   # Session, etc.

   # Now, go over the list of images one by one
   for url in url_list:
      image = ... # get image
      features = session.run(...) # extract features
```

Comment: I agree this is much better coding practice. I'll actually go ahead and refactor the entire code so that I don't have to load the model more than once.

I do wish I knew why exactly my code as written went wrong, though.

Comment: I think, the actual problem is: you re-define the input (input_tensor), instead of using the input placeholder which is already available in the model. So, you should have a look at the `input` within you model and feed it with the image.